# function --> many different textareas, but one specific id

Tags: javascript, html, function, textarea

i got the following function:

```
function add() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    document.getElementById("tt5").innerHTML += b + " ";
  }
}
```

after click on button --> 50 different integers (from 1-50) will be outputted in textarea("tt5")
but now I got like 2 additional textareas, with the same id="tt5",
but it's not affecting them at all...

```
<button onclick="add()">OK</button>
<textarea class="textarea2" name="t5" id="tt5"></textarea>
<textarea class="textarea3" name="t5" id="tt5"></textarea>
<textarea class="textarea4" name="t5" id="tt5"></textarea>
```

I want all textareas, to be filled with the add-function()

Comment: *"with the same id"* - That's why.  The `id` values need to be unique.  The browser can't *id*entify something that's non-unique.  Perhaps you meant to identify them by a class instead?

Comment: by class, but "document.getElementByCLASS? is there such a thing ?

Comment: Of course :) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: omg, that's awesome !!! thx ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got something key backwards in your markup.  You're using unique *classes* and non-unique *ids*.  It should be the other way around:

```
<textarea class="textarea" name="t5" id="tt1"></textarea>
<textarea class="textarea" name="t5" id="tt2"></textarea>
<textarea class="textarea" name="t5" id="tt3"></textarea>
```

This is because any `id` in the DOM needs to be unique ("id" is short for "identifier").  But you can apply classes anywhere you like.  Then you can use a different function to get an array of matching elements:

```
var textareas = document.document.getElementsByClassName("textarea");
for (var j = 0; j < textareas.length; j++) {
    textareas[j].innerHTML += b + " ";
}
```

There are some more advanced ways of applying something across multiple elements or applying a function multiple times to an array, but as you're already familiar with loops and such this should at least be enough to get started.  Note also that repeating `name` values may have unexpected consequences if you're submitting a form at all.  The key/value pairs sent to the server need unique names.

Comment: well explained // that's just great